# custom type mat tabs for ngx-formly, does not render the content of all tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-formly

I'm having trouble creating a custom type, I based it on the library (https://github.com/franzeal/ngx-formly-tabs), but only the contents of the last TAB appear.

I have a demo on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tabs-vimbo-form

When I have more than one TAB, only the last one appears and I don't know where I may be wrong and how I can correct it.
If anyone can help me.

**Edit 1:**
Solved, https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tabs-vimbo-form